# I just started this subject and I´d like to know how to solve this type of exersises by the properties.

Tags: summation

I have this:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^{5}\frac{i}{i+1}$

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{i}{i*1}$? Normally $*$ is multiply so this would just be equal to 1.

Comment: My mistake, It´s a "+".

Comment: https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/sequences/sequences.html I think this website have the answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=2}^5 \frac{i}{i+1} = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{4}{5} + \frac{5}{6} = \frac{61}{20}$$

Comment: Might try to even write $\frac{2}{2+1}$ instead, at this point it is not clear what does the OP not understand.

Comment: and what if I have a 1000 in n?